# Estimates for the wave equation

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Spose $ u $ solves the wave equation on $ U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $ with initial conditions $ u (x, 0) = g(x)$ and $ u_t(x,0) = h(x)$, where lower script indicates partial differentiation. Then we have

$\int _U u_t^2 + |\nabla u|^2 \leq \int _U h^2 + |\nabla g|^2 $.

My question is then does this give me some bounds (control) on $u$ in terms of $g$ and $h$? If so how do I show this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should just be able to use Poincare I guess.

Comment: Poincare isnt something I wanted to use (I don't want u to have to vanish on the boundary of $U$

Comment: What boundary conditions do you have, if any? Without any idea of the boundary condition, I don't see why what you wrote should be true

Answer (score 0):

You jute have to multiply the wave equation by $u_t$,we find $E_t(t)=0$, where $E$ is the energy functional. Integrating over $(0,t)$ we find $E(t)=E(0)$ and this is what you are asking for.